# Show $G \times \{e_H\}$ is a normal subgroup of $G \times H$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show $G \times \{e_H\}$ is a normal subgroup of $G \times H$

Would using the kernel of a group homomorphism be the best choice for this?

or

Suppose $G \times \{e_H\}$  is normal

$(g,h)*(g_i, e_H)*(g^{-1},h^{-1})=(gg_ig^{-1}, e_H) $

this gives $(g,h)G\times\{e_H\}(g,h)^{-1} \subseteq G\times\{e_H\}$

Now, suppose  $(g,h)G\times\{e_H\}(g,h)^{-1} \subseteq G\times\{e_H\}$

for $(g,h) \in G \times H, (g,h)G\times\{e_H\}(g,h)^{-1} \subseteq G\times\{e_H\} \implies (g,h)G\times\{e_H\} \subseteq G\times\{e_H\}(g,h)$

and for $(g,h)^{-1} \in G \times H, (g,h)^{-1}G\times\{e_H\}((g,h)^{-1})^{-1} \subseteq G\times\{e_H\}\implies G\times\{e_H\}(g,h) \subseteq (g,h)G\times\{e_H\}$

Thus $(g,h)G\times\{e_H\} = G\times\{e_H\}(g,h)$ therefore $G \times \{e\}$ is a normal subgroup of $G \times H$

Comment: You cannot prove that a certain subgroup is normal and start the argument with «Assume that the subgroup is normal»!

Comment: Do not assume is normal, it is straight forward by "conjugation". Thinking of it as the kernel is also really easy, consider the homomorphism that is trivial in $G$ and the identity in $H$.

Comment: the trivial homomorphism being the one sending all G to the identity of G and $e_H \to e_H$ ?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Why can't I assume when I am proving it in a "if and only if" way?

Comment: What do you gain by assuming it's true? Why not just say, "Assume it's true, QED!"? The homomorphism you suggested would send all of $G \times H$ to the identity of $G \times H$. Two obvious target groups would be $G$ or $H$, do either seem promising?

Comment: @oliverjones, what you want to prove is not an if and only if. You want to prove that «$G\times\{e_H\}$ is normal in $G\times H$», which has no «if and only if in it» at all.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Looking at this : https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Normal_Subgroup_Test 
it seems like its valid. Im not really clear on how to use the kernel to show its normal

Comment: @oliverjones No: the «iff» you see there is a *definition*.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez okay that makes sense, if the first part is left out is the part starting "now, suppose $(g,h)G\times\{e_H\}(g,h)^{-1} \subseteq G\times\{e_H\}$" correct to use from there on out?

How would I use the kernel?

Comment: If $\phi(g,h) = h$, h is forced to be $e_H$ and g can be any $g \in G$ so $ker(\phi)=\{(g,e_H)|g\in G\} = G \times \{e_H\}$ and  $\forall (g,h) \in G \times H, \,\, \phi(g^{1},h^{-1})\phi(g_i,h)\phi(g,h) = \phi(g^{-1}g_ig,h_i) = h = e_H \in ker(\phi)$ Like that?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to *show* is that for *any* $g \in G$, and any $(x,y) \in G \times H$, we have:

$(x,y)(g,e_H)(x,y)^{-1} \in G \times \{e_H\}$.

What do you obtain by multiplying out the above expression:

$(x,y)(g,e_H)(x,y)^{-1}$?